# Set environmental variables in a particular directory

Tags: linux, bash, variables

This is a .bashrc question.
I would like to set `"export FOO=bar"` for .bashrc in a particular directory like `.rvmrc`.

I tried below.

```
$ touch ~/foo/.bashrc
$ echo 'export RAILS_ENV=development' >> ~/foo/.bashrc
$ cd foo/
$ env|grep RAILS_ENV
```

But `RAILS_ENV` shall be set nothing in this case.

If I set onto `.rvmrc` instead of .bashrc, it pass! But it is better way to set onto `.bashrc` because I do not need to install rvm environment.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your bashrc set this:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $PWD == "/foo/bar/" ]] && export FOO=BAR || unset FOO'
```

The contents of the PROMPT_COMMAND variable will be executed every time your prompt is rewritten ( just before it's written actually ) the command above checks the $PWD variable ( which holds the current working directory of your shell ) against "/foo/bar" if it matches it exports your variable if it doesn't then the variable is unset.

EG

```
peteches@yog-sothoth$ PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $PWD == "/home/peteches/test" ]] && export FOO=BAR || unset FOO'
peteches@yog-sothoth$ pwd
/home/peteches
peteches@yog-sothoth$ cd test
peteches@yog-sothoth$ pwd
/home/peteches/test
peteches@yog-sothoth$ env | grep FOO
6:FOO=BAR
73:PROMPT_COMMAND=[[ $PWD == "/home/peteches/test" ]] && export FOO=BAR || unset FOO
peteches@yog-sothoth$ cd ../
peteches@yog-sothoth$ pwd
/home/peteches
peteches@yog-sothoth$ env | grep FOO
72:PROMPT_COMMAND=[[ $PWD == "/home/peteches/test" ]] && export FOO=BAR || unset FOO
peteches@yog-sothoth$
```

Comment: Cool! This is what I want!

Comment: @gipcompany, if this is the correct answer to your question, reward the answer by accepting it: click the checkmark beside the answer.

Comment: I want to combine this answer with the mycd() answer below in order to set up multiple directories with different env vars (and get away from the one-liner syntax). Is it possible to assign a function like Davide's mycd() to PROMPT_COMMAND?

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, but it might be convenient to make it more general. Since the OP seems to want $dir/.bashrc to apply, perhaps change PROMPT_COMMAND to look for `./.bash-dir-cfg` (or similar) and source it if it exists.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind to use a workaround, add this to your `.bash_profile`

```
mycd()
{
    cd $1
    if [ "$(pwd)" == "/your/folder/that/needs/env" ]; then
        export RAILS_ENV=development
    else
        export RAILS_ENV=
    fi;
}
alias cd=mycd
```

Everytime you move to a certain folder this will set your env variable or whatever you want

Comment: Nice! I also like that environment variables are only set once, when you `cd` into the directory, instead of before any command as seems to be the case with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [`direnv`](https://github.com/direnv/direnv)

> `direnv` is an extension for your shell. It augments existing shells with a new feature that can load and unload environment variables depending on the current directory.

Basically checks for `.envrc` files located in the current or parent directories, and adjusts your environment variables accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

First, AFAIK, `bash` won't search for a `.bashrc` file in any other directory but your home -- at least, not by default.

Secondly, after writing new entries to your `.bashrc`, you should `source .bashrc` the file, so that modifications take place.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, .bashrc can not be loaded automatically in case of 'cd foo'.

Comment: @gipcompany You're welcome, and that's the exact reason why you had no output after greping for `RAILS_ENV`. As some answer presented, you may add the `source'ing` step after each `cd`, but in your particular case it may be better to simply source the `.bashrc` content manually.