# How to set different user.name and user.email for each Git branch?

Tags: git

Suppose I am using a shared computer account and working on a repository with multiple branches, each branch developed by a different user on that same computer account. It would be helpful to not have to switch the user.name and user.email every time a different user uses the computer to make commits to the repository.

How do I set a different user.name and user.email for each branch?

Comment: Are you logging in on the computer or are you sharing the computer account as well?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sharing the same computer account.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach is to:

- not rely on a local configuration to the repo
- rely only on the global configuration (the one in $HOME/.gitconfig)

That way, each user naturally has his/her own user.name/user.email whenever he/she does any commit in a shared repo.

If you really need to only update a branch per user, you could add a pre-commit hook making sure the right branch is about to be committed.

If you are using the same computer account:

a/ don't ;) It is not a best practice to share account
b/ setup an alias (one per user) which would setup that config

One approach that might work is:

- use [`git worktree` to get one folder per branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) (instead of cloning your all repo multiple times)
- change your prompt in order to set the right `user.name` (environment variable `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`) and user.email (`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`): see "[Set environmental variables in a particular directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462591/set-environmental-variables-in-a-particular-directory)"

Answer (score 1):

Make a clone for each of you. Run `git config --local user.name xxx` and `git config --local user.email xxx@yyy.zz` in each clone. `--local` can be omitted since it's the default.

But why not create an account for each of you in the same computer?

Comment: I suspect the answer to your question may be of a programmatic nature? A script may run git commands on behalf of a synthetic user as this user may not exist on the native OS -only in the "script-verse".